# HowTo combine huge ASP Classic site with .Net

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, oracle, asp-classic

I'm running a large classic-asp site (self-developed) for a public library (25k users) which actually performs really good (oracle 11g r2 database), but from time to time new services need to be added or old ones adapted.

And there's my dilemma. Every time I work on this site I feel like I should not update this outdated monster no more and that I should port it to a up to date technology. But how to start? I have good knowledge in developing asp.net (vb.net) websites and I’m searching for a way to rewrite code in .net (Webforms, MVC, WebApi, ... ?) and integrate it part by part into the classic asp site, (I can't rewrite the whole thing at once, because I haven't enough time!) so that some time from now on the site will be completely rewritten.

Another thing I need to consider is the Oracle DB and the already existing and optimized (and often oracle specific) SQL statements that I definitely want to use in the new built (so entity framework and linq seems not an option).

I was thinking about using the new WebApi and call the actions via jQuery from the classic asp site, but couldn't find an easy way to interact it with ODP (returning and accepting Json).

I'm really hoping for anyone to point me into the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

If possible you will need to break your existing website into modules can be separated out and rewritten individually.

Because you are doing such a massive rework between an outdated technology (classic ASP) and bleeding edge (WebAPI etc), it probably won't be possible to run the two as a single application. You will instead have to run two separate applications side by side which will behave as a single application for the user. Part by part you will move your separated modules from the old application to the new.

If you want to continue using Oracle, it's still possible to use Linq and Entity Framework as these are used for querying your data rather than actually storing it. You can use Oracle, MSSQL or even one of the newer document databases such as Mongo or Raven DB.

Comment: Thanks for your input. After looking into Linq to Entities a little more (works well with EF5 and Oracle) i think i'll give ASP.NET WebApi and MVC a shot!

Comment: Not a problem, glad you found something you think should work. Sounds like it's going to be an interesting (and challenging) project :) Feel free to mark as answer if you think it helped!